# Auto importing and updating pom.xml [inteliJ idea 13]

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

if i add library from maven repository into my project (via its IDE's ui) then inteliJ ideadon't write its dependency in `pom.xml` file.

why? how? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to preferences->maven->importing-> check the Import Maven project automatically. Also, I recommend to go on tab maven and do reimport sometimes Intellij really don't read pom.xml even if all settings turn on.

Comment: sorry andrey, auto importing is just kinnda read operation where ide read pom and tell maven to solve dependecies but, i want ide to write pox.xml when i import lib from ide's own iterface, i don't wanant write pom.xml each time.